# Using gnuplot, how to obtain a PDF with canvas size, including the texts?

Tags: latex, gnuplot, pdflatex

## Question

I want
[image]
neither
[image]
nor
[image]

## Description

The first figure is what I want.
The second figure is obtained by

```
set terminal cairolatex pdf
set output 'cairolatex.pdf'
set xlabel '$\sigma$'
set ylabel '$\alpha$'
plot 'data' u 1:2 w l
```

For the third figure, first

```
set terminal cairolatex pdf
set output 'cairolatex.tex'
set xlabel '$\sigma$'
set ylabel '$\alpha$'
plot 'data' u 1:2 w l
```

Then

```sh
pdflatex plot.tex
```

where `plot.tex` is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

Edit:
Thanks to Ethan, I can reach
[image]
by

```
set term pdf size 10cm,7cm
set output 'term.pdf'
set xlabel '$\sigma$'
set ylabel '$\alpha$'
plot 'data' u 1:2 w l
```

But I want to use latex typesetting for `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, revised answer to produce a figure using TeX typesetting.  Several gnuplot terminals could do this but I recommend using tikz.

```
set term tikz standalone size 12cm, 7cm
set output 'figure.tex'
set xlabel '$\sigma$'
set ylabel '$\alpha$' offset -2
set xrange [1:7]
set lmargin 12
set border lw 2
plot 10.**x title '$10^x$'
unset output
!pdflatex figure
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an Edit to the question. I want to use latex typesetting for xlabel and ylabel (and other texts). At the same time, I want the size of the generated pdf to be like what you proposed, not an A4 paper.